# CSS media queries not working anywhere

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to use different CSS Stylesheets for different layouts (as you have already guessed from the title) but unfortunately nothing is working.

I tried loading the CSS file

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/medium-main.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" />
```

in the meta tag and I also tried using

```
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
.page{max-width:730px; margin:0 auto; display: block; height:850px;  float:left; }
  }
```

in the main css file but no changes occur.

This is how my header looks like:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image-slides.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/medium-main.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" />
```

The CSS property that I am trying to change is a simple's div's width and so when I resize the browser nothing happens.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you reproduce this with jsfiddle.com or jsbin.com?

Comment: what browser are you trying this on? also when you inspect the page div, is your styles getting overridden or does it not appear at all

Comment: Is literally nothing working? cause you may have mistyped the path of the css file somewhere. Also is the bootstrap's css media queries interfering with your media query?

Comment: @Huangism this is happeing in firefox

Comment: @ak_47 so what do you see when you inspect(firebug) your page div? media query style not there or getting overridden?

Comment: @ak_47 [It works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/dpka3/).

Comment: @Huangism under 800 px i dont see any changes.media query style not there

Comment: @ak_47 well then your styles probably not even on the page. Try to access the css by entering the URL in the address bar and see if it comes up like www.domain.com/folders/css/cssName.css

Comment: sometimes cache prevent css changes result from showed up immediately. Try refreshing or reloading your page instead of reopen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply try the code like following to make your site responsive to make changes on phone view as well on resizing , I don't think where are exactly making bug in your code , but the given code works for me well :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='stylesheets/narrow.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='stylesheets/medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='stylesheets/wide.css' />
```

Answer (score 10):

Is your HTML properly set as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    //stuff
</body>
</html>
```

Use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) { … }
```

Instead of:

```
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) { … }
```

Comment: It's embarrassing how many times I've had to Google this only to remember I'm missing my `<meta name="viewport" ...>` tag...

Answer (score 5):

I think that is the way of ordering code.

Original CSS code should be placed first, then other screen with `@media` ordered by size:

```
...original CSS code...

@media(max-width:300px) {...}  

@media(max-width:533px) {...}  

@media(max-width:640px) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@media all  and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    /*your code here*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

[Here](http://tecrive.com/old_website/testing/Grid_Responsive.html) is an example. It is responsive design.